# when I set the variable "shuffle = False" of the function tf.trian.string_input_producer,the test accuracy reduced

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing a image classification task using tensorflow. Here is part of my code:

```
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"), tf.name_scope(scope):
            input_ops['id'] = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            tf.convert_to_tensor(data_id),
                capacity=128
            #   shuffle = False
            ).dequeue(name='input_ids_dequeue')

            m, label = dataset.get_data(data_id[0])
```

After training, In the test phrase, The default value of variable "shuffle" in the function tf.trian.string_input_producer is Ture, but I don't want the shuffled prediction labels, so I set the shuffle = False, then, the test accuracy reduced a lot. I want to know what is the problems with it?

Comment: It is probably having more of an issue with over fitting when you have shuffle set to False.

Comment: +1 I don't see how shuffling or not can impact your accuracy. Accuracy going down on test data is very common. As paul41 mentioned, it is called overfitting. Try measuring the accuracy on shuffled data. I bet you will find the same low result.

Comment: I comfirm that I have finished the training phrase, trust me that when I‘m testing, if the "shuffle = True", the test accuracy is high to 98%, and if I changed the shuffle to False,and didn't change anything more, the test accuracy is much lower to 86%. I don't believe it either, but the experiment result shows that, so I'm much confused.